# keep the same name until value = true in another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:  `session_id`, `name`, `reset_flag`.

I need to make a new column, `new_name`, where the new name will be set to the first `name` where `reset_flag=True`, and then it will continue as that name WITHIN that session, until there is new `reset_flag`.

Not really sure best way to approach.

EDIT: I thought of a way to do so with df.iterrows(), by storing into list and then appending, but it seems very bulky.  is there a more efficient 'pandas' way?

Sample expected output

| session_id | name | reset_flag | new_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_1 | TRUE | some_name_1 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_1 |  | some_name_1 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_1 |  | some_name_1 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_2 | TRUE | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_2 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_2 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_3 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_3 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_4 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_4 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_4 |  | some_name_2 |
| 06c97a-bc7-6cc-29f-65978ee8d | some_name_5 | TRUE | some_name_5 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_1 | TRUE | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_1 |  | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_1 |  | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_2 |  | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_2 |  | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_2 |  | some_name_1 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_3 | TRUE | some_name_3 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_3 |  | some_name_3 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_4 |  | some_name_3 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_4 |  | some_name_3 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_4 |  | some_name_3 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_5 | TRUE | some_name_5 |
| 3943d5-e1e-63e-6c4-aa1899bd9 | some_name_6 |  | some_name_5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to go about this would be to use `cumsum` on the "reset_flag" column : this will give you a columns of numbers that increase every time a `True` is encountered.

You can then simply group by this column to get the desired result (I'm assuming your "reset_flag" column is boolean):

```py
df["new_name"] = df.groupby(df["reset_flag"].cumsum())["name"].transform("first")
```

Comment: Just a question.  In this case, NAN values should be replaced for FALSE before?  Is it a good practice?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming the `reset_flag` column is boolean, so you might need to use `fillna(False)` before the `cumsum`. Another option could be to call numpy's `nancumsum` on that column directly.

Answer (score 1):

Apply new name and then fillna

```
df['new_name'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['name'] if r['reset_flag'] else np.nan, aixs=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is more efficient way of doing it, but this should work:

```
df['new_name'] = np.nan

session_name = np.nan

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  # I assume the 'TRUE' in your col is str. 
  if row['reset_flag'] == 'TRUE':
    df['new_name'][index] = row['name']
    session_name = row['name']
  else: 
    df['new_name'][index] = session_name
```